# Pyramid with Deform not rendering properly. Rendered as pure string

Tags: python, pyramid, forms, colander, deform

I am trying out pyramid with deform. However the form is not rendered as form but a pure string

```
@view_config(route_name='sign_up', renderer='templates/sign_up.jinja2')
def sign_up(request):
    schema = SignUpForm().bind(request=request)

    button = deform.form.Button(name='SignUp', title = 'Sign Up')
    form = deform.form.Form(schema, buttons=(button, ))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            appstruct = form.validate(request.POST.items())

            # Save the data to database
            print('saved')
            print(appstruct['username'])

            request.session.flash('your have succesfully registered')

            return HTTPFound('/')
        except deform.exception.ValidationFailure as e:
            rendered_form = form.render()
    else:
        print('rendering the form')
        rendered_form = form.render();

    return {'rendered_form': rendered_form}
```

This is my HTML using Jinja2 templating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
            {{rendered_form}}
    </body>
</html>
```

All the form information shows up as pure literal string like `<form method=POST>` etc in the browser

```
class SignUpForm(deform.schema.CSRFSchema):
    username = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.String(),
        title = 'Username')
    password = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.String(),
        title = 'Password')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja2 is configured to auto-escape any variables in your template to avoid XSS attacks from untrusted markup in variables. You can turn off auto-escaping for the form (because deform can be trusted to escape the rendered data on its own) via `{{ rendered_form | safe }}`.